# Producing a book class document with a specific background image on a specific part interstitial and chapter interstitial page

Tags: backgrounds

I am preparing a document using a custom book class with LuaLaTeX. The book has parts as well as chapters, with blank pages created at the end of chapters and parts as necessary so that the first page of parts and chapters are on the right side.

I would like to place a specific background image on a specific one of these blank pages. I've explored the `background` and `eso-pic` packages. The closest I've been able to come is with the `background` package and, where I was able to place a specific image on all pages of a specific part, including the empty part. I then tried to nest another `if` to select the page based on whether the `pagestyle` is empty.

The following produces one specific background image for all pages of Part 2 and another specific image for all pages of Part 3.

The root file is listed below. I tried adding the class file and the first two included files but the character limit on posts would not allow it.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book-based-class}
\usepackage[contents={},pages=some]{background}
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifnum\value{part}=2\relax
\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  opacity=0.5,
  contents={
    \includegraphics{part-image-2}}
}
\fi
\ifnum\value{part}=3\relax
\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  opacity=0.5,
  contents={
    \includegraphics{part-image-3}}
}
\fi
\BgMaterial
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\include{./tex/book-test-frontmatter}

\mainmatter
\part{The First Part}
\include{./tex/the-first-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-second-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-third-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-fourth-chapter}
\part{The Second Part}
\include{./tex/the-fifth-chaptery}
\include{./tex/the-sixth-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-seventh-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-eighth-chapter}
\part{The Third Part}
\include{./tex/the-nineth-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-tenth-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-eleventh-chapter}
\part{The Fourht Part}
\include{./tex/the-twelveth-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-thirteenth-chapter}
\part{The Fifth Part}
\include{./tex/the-fourteenth-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-fifteenth-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-sixteenth-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-seventeenth-chapter}
\include{./tex/the-eighteenth-chapter}
\backmatter
\CookbookIndex{}
\end{document}
```

I later tried to add a nested if to test whether the pagestyle is `empty` and produce an image if true, and nothing if the pagestyle is NOT `empty` using `ifthenelse`. This had no effect.

I tried replacing `part` in the above with `chapter` and `page` changing the value appropriately. But this had no effect.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please complete your code so it can be compiled?

Comment: I edited the post to include code that compiles. It produces a specific background image on all pages of the second part, and another specific background image on all pages of the third part. I tried to include the class file and two of the included files but the character limit of posts wont allow it.

Comment: If I could modify the above code to test for a page number instead of a section number, it would be enough to produce the results that I want.

Comment: Hey @BAK. I see you're new here, so let me explain things a little better. Asking a question is easy. Asking a *good* question is not so easy. You should put yourself in the shoes of the audience reading your question and try to imagine them (us) compiling your document. Since you're limited in terms of the character count, take that into account when posting. For example, is it really necessary to use `book-based-class`, or would `book` suffice to replicate the problem? ...

Comment: ... What about all those things you include (`book-test-frontmatter.tex`). Is it really necessary, or would [`lipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) text suffice? Or the images (`part-image-1`, `part-image-2`, ...)? We don't have those. Ideally we want a minimal, working example (or MWE for short). This allows us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. More information regarding content for a MWE: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: Replacing the block with AddEverypageHook with the following does what I want, except for one problem, it produces an image on page viii of the frontmatter as well as page 8 of the mainmatter: \usepackage[contents={},pages=some]{background}
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifnum\value{page}=2\relax
\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  opacity=0.5,
  contents={
    \includegraphics{chapter-image-5}}
}
\fi
\ifnum\value{page}=8\relax
\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  opacity=0.5,
  contents={
    \includegraphics{chapter-image-5}}
}
\fi
\BgMaterial
}